# How to add existing local files from different servers to git repository branches?

Tags: git, version-control

Trying to learn about git, I've seen a lot of documentation, but have almost zero real experience with git. So you can say I know about all the basic concept about git. But that's all.

Now, we are at a point that we realised we could maybe benefit from git, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I got 3 servers with source code in them, one for Dev, one preprod, and one prod. All files should be almost identical, but its possible that the dev/preprod might be a bit more recent.

So I created my git repo, created 2 branch, dev and preprod.

Added my dev files to dev, preprod to preprod. Did a compare between the two, and to my surprise files are seeing as different, probably because they are not seen as the same file.

How should I proceed with this ?

Once everything will be in my git repo, on my dev server, I'll always pull stuff from dev, preprod, I'll pull and merge in preprod, and master I'll always pull from dev and preprod, and merge.

Do I have a good understanding ? And how can I import my files from my different environnements ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the right one as far as I can see. Though I would start over again in your case.

Instead of comparing the files in the two branches, try to bring them in order first. From your description I would say that your stuff in prod is "the oldest", than preprod, than dev.

Say you create first a repo and import everything from prod in master. Than branch it to prod. After that checkout master again and try to import preprod by just replacing the files in the folder. git diff than tells you what changed. It'll be easy to spot small diffs like whitespaces and so that you can ignore in the next step. I suggest git add -i (for interactive) for the job. Than commit what you have and branch it to preprod.

At last, repeat the procedure with dev and keep it there. This way master would be your dev. Some people like it that way, some don't. It's just an option.

Note that code that is different in every branch maybe is just configuration that you can outsource in a configuration file that isn't part of the repository.

Maybe also interesting for you it that article about branching models: [A successfull Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

In fact the tool git-flow, which is a helper for workflows with git, is based on this model and is supported in some enterprise tools like bitbucket.

The right way is the one you and your team can work with and not the one with the most magic though :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the same file in `dev` branch and `preprod` branch with same content, but you found the different by `git diff dev preprod`, It’s mainly because **they have different counts of blank lines** (such as file in `dev` branch has one blank line, but in `preprod` it has two blank lines in the end of content). So git treat they are different.

Yes, you can pull/merge from `dev` and `preprod` servers. But there has better way to sync the code in dev server with preprod server. You can use **post-receive hook**. After you push changes to dev server, you can use a post-receive hook to sync preprod server with dev server.

Comment: I didn't knew about post-receive hook! Thanks for the tip!